# Soldiers and artillery guns

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I have a question in my homework which says: 
Soldiers who fire artillery guns never stand behind the gun. Why?

What could be some good reasons for this and which of Newton’s laws would cause this ?

Comment: So they stand in front? What do you think will be the forces acting? Draw a picture and show what you think so far...

Comment: We are not allowed to answer homework questions but [this video may give you a clue](https://www.military.com/video/guns/artillery/150mm-artillery-recoil-knocks-german-out/661752685001) and [another](https://www.military.com/video/guns/recoil/one-extremely-painful-cannon-recoil/1042485432001)

Comment: Did you have a question about a spaceman marooned outside the spaceship a bit ago?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question should be pretty obvious. With artillery pieces there is a very large recoil which in the old days caused the piece to suddenly jerk backwards several feet or even yards. Modern methods of absorbing recoil have greatly reduced this problem, but it is still unwise to stand directly behind an artillery piece when firing. I was once in charge of a 90mm anti-tank gun and fired it a number of times without mishap, but I never stood directly behind it. When my unit was about to return to Blighty, I handed the gun over to another man and demonstrated how to use it. A few months later I was told that the gun had exploded and the breech block had cut him in half. Faulty ammunition was said to be the cause.